# DELL Power edge 2900 reinstallation

Tags: dell-poweredge, windows-server-2003-r2, drivers

we are looking forward to upgrade our DELL power edge server to windows 2003 64bit operating system, however now it requires to start from scratch. unfortunately i do not have the driver or start up disks to initiate the installation, can we simply boot from the windows disk and go through the installation process. any assistance will be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

I am not familiar with Dell at all, but I found [Dell Installation and Server Management Disk](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&cs=RC1078552&l=en&s=gen&releaseid=R146318&formatcnt=0&libid=0&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=204270) available to download (and burn of course).

> Compatibility: PowerEdge 2900
>   Microsoft Windows Server 2003 x64

There is also some instruction [here](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/software/win2003/ws2k3_x6/en/ins_ismc/dcinen.pdf).

Comment: Get the Service Tag (Dell's name for the serial #), enter it into the System Configuration link on http://support.dell.com.  This will provide the original hardware config.  Use this info to download the needed drivers.  The install can be done w/ the above install disk or the W2k8 install media + downloaded drivers for the storage controller. Once the OS is installed then use the downloaded drivers to complete the install.

Comment: Thanks Grzegorz, i managed to download the installation server management disk. i recon this will make the process running smooth.

Answer (score 2):

Installing Server 2003 x64 on a Poweredge 2950 with Perc 5i / 6i (LSI logic) RAID drivers.

This was a nightmare but i finally figured out how to get windows setup to read my RAID drive (In my case i couldn’t use Dell’s System Build and Update Utility disc because it wants to format the entire RAID disk… i just wanted to repair my install).

The Windows Server 2003 R2 x64 installation disc will not recognize your LSI perc raid card without installing third party drivers.  This becomes complicated as there is no floppy drive with the power edge 2950 and just sticking the drivers on a usb stick won’t cut it.  Luckily I figured out how to get windows setup to recognize your raid drive.

Basically you have to create a USB floppy drive with your usb stick and place the drivers on it.

Step by step instructions can be found [here](http://brakertech.com/poweredge-2950-server-2003-install-raid-driver-repair-window/)

Answer (score 0):

While you SHOULD use the disk Grzegorz Szpetkowski mentions, you CAN slipstream the disk controller drivers into a new 2003 disc that you can then use to install.  (I BELIEVE [nlite](http://www.nliteos.com) works with x64 versions of Windows, but even if it doesn't there are manual ways to slipstream).